# How to dismiss dialog when attached to activity?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain `MainActivity`and that activity contains a `fragment` which send server request and during that i am showing a `ProgressDialog`. But while progress dialog is displaying, if i move from `MainActivity` to another activity it was giving me error `"Fragment not attached to activity"`.

How can i resolve this issue?

**code:-**

```
    /*This method send request to server for more deals*/
private void loadmoreData() {
    if (mSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {
        mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
    }
    try {
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put(ServerRequestKeyStorage.s_szAGENT_CODE, m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put(ServerRequestKeyStorage.s_szPASSWORD, m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password
        jsonObject.put(ServerRequestKeyStorage.s_szRECORD_COUNT, sz_RecordCount);// put record count
        jsonObject.put(ServerRequestKeyStorage.s_szLAST_COUNT, sz_LastCount);// put last count
        Log.d("CAppList:", sz_RecordCount);
        Log.d("Capplist:", sz_LastCount);
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to  string
        Log.i(TAG, "Server Request:-" + json);
        m_Dialog = DialogUtils.showProgressDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.loading_more_deals));


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        final String imgPath = APIStorage.IREWARDS_URL + APIStorage.s_szImagePath;
        final String m_DealListingURL = APIStorage.IREWARDS_URL + APIStorage.s_szDEALLISTING_URL;
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server Response:-" + response);

                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (activity!=null&&isAdded()){
                    m_Dialog.dismiss();
                }

                try {
                    int nResultCodeFromServer = Integer.parseInt(response.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szRESULT_CODE));

                    if (nResultCodeFromServer == CStaticVar.m_kTRANSACTION_SUCCESS) {
                        // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
                        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_ARRAY);// GETTING DEAL LIST
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                                item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// object create of DealAppdatastorage
                                item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_NAME));//getting deal name
                                item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_CODE));// getting deal code
                                item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_VAlUE));
                                item.setM_szDetails(post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_DETAILS));
                                String logo = post.getString(ServerResponseStorage.s_szDEAL_LOGO);
                                item.setM_szLogoPath(imgPath + logo);
                                Log.e(TAG, "Logo Path::" + item.getM_szLogoPath());
                                if (!s_oDataset.contains(item)) {
                                    s_oDataset.add(item);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        m_oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        arrayCount = posts.length();// finding length of deals coming in response from server.
                        // read stored value from shared preference
                        int n_oLastCountLength = m_oPreferenceHelper.getIntPreference(LAST_COUNT_LENGTH);
                        int accumulateLastCount = n_oLastCountLength + arrayCount;


                        /*Here we are saving deal length in shared preference*/
                        // save incremental length
                        m_oPreferenceHelper.saveIntegerValue(LAST_COUNT_LENGTH, accumulateLastCount);
                        //                          m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
                        m_ListView.setSelection(m_oAdapter.getCount() - posts.length());

                    }

                    if (nResultCodeFromServer == CStaticVar.m_kCONNECTION_LOST) {//server based conditions
                        CSnackBar.showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, getString(R.string.connection_not_available), getActivity());
                       //                           m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == CStaticVar.m_kDEAL_NOT_FOUND) {// serevr based conditions .....
                        CSnackBar.showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, getString(R.string.no_more_deals), getActivity());
                      //                            //*Counting loading footer*/
                     //                         if (m_ListView.getFooterViewsCount() != 0) {
                    //                              m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
                   //                           }
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == CStaticVar.m_kTECHNICAL_FAILURE) {
                        CSnackBar.showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, getString(R.string.technical_failure), getActivity());
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == CStaticVar.m_kALREADY_AVAIL_BENEFIT) {
                        CSnackBar.showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, getString(R.string.already_avail_deals), getActivity());
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == CStaticVar.m_kTIMED_OUT) {
                        CSnackBar.showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, getString(R.string.times_out), getActivity());
                //                          m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == CStaticVar.m_kERROR_IN_DB) {
                        CSnackBar.showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, "Something happened wrong in DB. Please contact support@starxsoft.com", getActivity());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server Error::" + error);
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (activity!=null&&isAdded()){
                    m_Dialog.dismiss();
                }
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    CSnackBar.showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, getString(R.string.connection_timed_out), getActivity());
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    CSnackBar.showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, getString(R.string.no_internet_warning), getActivity());
                }
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In this during dismiss and showing a dialog it gives me error.

Comment: Call `dismiss` before moving to next Activity

Comment: code pls....................

Comment: Before you dismiss the dialog you have to check fragment is visible or not. Using `isVisible()`. For More information refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isVisible())

Comment: if(isVisible){mDialog.dismiss}else{//what to do here}

Comment: @Vishal try this way. if (m_Dialog!=null && isVisible()){
                    m_Dialog.dismiss();
                }

Comment: ok i don't have to write above code when showing dialog only in dissmissing dialog.

Comment: I am correct or not

Comment: Only at time of dismissing